# Imprimir un nombre compuesto en forma triángulo - JAVA

Tags: java, string, substring

Hola muy buenas estoy empezando con el lenguaje JAVA y he tenido el siguiente problema: el ejercicio pide al usuario un nombre y a continuación muestra la formación de dicho nombre concatenando letra por letra. Ejemplo:

Si introduce Jaime, mostrará:
J
Ja
Jai
Jaim
Jaime

El problema viene cuando el nombre es compuesto. Si introduce Jose Maria, muestra:

- J
- Jo
- Jos
- Jose
- **Jose** (Este resultado es el que quiero evitar)
- Jose M
- Jose Ma
- Jose Mar
- Jose Mari
- Jose Maria

**Código JAVA**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NombreRepetido {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        String cadUsuario = "", cad = "", aux;

        int i = 0;  //Variable iteradora

        boolean salida = false;

        while(!salida) {

            System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre (exit para salir): ");
            aux = entrada.nextLine();

            if(aux.toLowerCase().equals("exit"))
                salida = true;
            else if (aux.isEmpty())
                System.out.println("Error: debes introducir una cadena de caracteres!");
            else {

                cadUsuario = aux;

                for(; i < cadUsuario.length(); i++){

                    cad += cadUsuario.substring(i, i + 1);

                    System.out.println(cad);

                }

                i = 0;
                cad = "";
            }

        }

        entrada.close();
        System.out.println("¡Hasta la próxima!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sólo te falta validar si el carácter actual es un espacio y, si es así, que lo añada a la cadena de salida sin imprimir y pase al siguiente en la cadena de entrada!

Comment: Ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se soluciona modificando el `for` donde imprimes las letras agregando un `if` que compare el valor actual de las letras concatenadas con el anterior y verificando que no sean iguales.

```
for (; i < cadUsuario.length(); i++) {
    String tmp = cad;
    cad += cadUsuario.substring(i, i + 1);

    if (!cad.trim().equals(tmp)) {
        System.out.println(cad);
    }
}
```